# Задать точку старта в ProgressBar

Tags: android, progress-bar

Есть ProgressBar

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="10"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar" />
```

preogressbar.xml

```
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" >
        <solid android:color="#51ff00" />

    </shape>

</item>
</layer-list>
```

Вопрос такой, как изменить точку старта у progressbar(в форме кольца), т.е. у меня в данный момент 0% находится справа(3 часа по часам), как сделать так чтобы старт был сверху(12 часов по часам).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код выдернул из своего проекта, все отлично работает.

**ProgressBar**

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_btn_popular"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:max="100"
android:progress="0"/>
```

**circular_progress_bar**

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="270"
android:toDegrees="270">
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="5dp"
    android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
</rotate>
```

**circle_shape**

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring"
android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
android:thickness="5dp"
android:useLevel="false">

<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

</shape>
```